# incompatible types: RecViewFragment cannot be converted to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, uinavigationbar

Earlier, my code was working fine but after some update in android studio gradle build, there is an error -  "error: incompatible types: RecViewFragment cannot be converted to Fragment
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new RecViewFragment()).commit();"
I tried import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class MainActivityBuses extends AppCompatActivity {

NavigationView nav;
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
Toolbar toolbar;
BottomNavigationView btmNav;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_buses);


toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

nav = findViewById(R.id.drawernav);
drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);

toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout, toolbar,R.string.open,R.string.close);
drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();

nav.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment selectdnav = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.dnavprofile:
                selectdnav = new MyProfileFragment();
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                break;
            case R.id.dnavmap:
                selectdnav = new MapFragment();
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                break;
            case R.id.dnavmybus:
                selectdnav = new BusFragment();
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                break;
            case R.id.dnavinfo:
                selectdnav = new InfoFragment();
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                break;
        }
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,selectdnav).commit();
        return true;
    }
});

        btmNav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.btmnav);
        btmNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener((navListner));
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new RecViewFragment()).commit();
        btmNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.navhome).setChecked(true);
    }
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListner = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment selectedFragment = null;
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.navprofile:
                    selectedFragment = new MyProfileFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new MyProfileFragment()).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.navmap:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivityBuses.this, MapActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                  

                    break;
                case R.id.navhome:
                    
                    selectedFragment = new RecViewFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new RecViewFragment()).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.navmybus:
                   
                    selectedFragment = new BusFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new BusFragment()).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.navinfo:
                   
                    selectedFragment = new InfoFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new InfoFragment()).commit();
                    break;
            }
          
            return true;
        }
    };


}
```

RecViewFragment class

```
package com.example.trackmybusstudent;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link RecViewFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class RecViewFragment extends Fragment {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ArrayList datalist;
FirebaseFirestore db;
myadapter myadap;

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";


    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public RecViewFragment() {
    }
    public static RecViewFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        RecViewFragment fragment = new RecViewFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rec_view, container, false);
       recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycleview);
       recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
       db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
       datalist = new ArrayList<>();
       myadap = new myadapter(datalist);
       recyclerView.setAdapter(myadap);
       db.collection("Bus_Database").orderBy("Route_Number", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
           @Override
           public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
               List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
               for(DocumentSnapshot d:list){
                   model obj = d.toObject(model.class);
                   datalist.add(obj);
                   myadap.notifyDataSetChanged();
               }
           }
       });
       return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your switch there's no default case, maybe you didn't set your ids correctly in the menu file, therefore selectdnav remains null.
I suggest you add a breakpoint to quickly analyze this.

Comment: i have cross checked my ids, they are fine. See, other fragments are working fine. So may, be there is some issue with the RecViewFragment class. Let me share the RecViewFragment class too.

Comment: I got the error. Now its working fine